# Extract and store the difference between two or more strings

Tags: python, variables

I need some help figuring out how to print the difference between two strings. I need the output to print the exact character difference between two strings, sometimes more than one character. Example of strings:

```py
str1 = "0074574-1"
str2 = "0074574+1"
```

The difference here is the `"+"` at the place of `"-"`.
Another example is

```py
str1 = "27785-74-1"
str2 = "27785%F274-1"
```

In this example the `"-"` is replaced by the characters `"%F2"`.
I need a code with the output from searching the difference between `str1` and `str2` as:

```py
diff_between_str1_str2 = "-"
```

or

```py
diff_between_str1_str2 = "%F2"
```

Can someone please point me into the right direction as to where I can begin to look?

Comment: There's `difflib` and specifically [`difflib.ndiff()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff)

Comment: Unless you're doing a character-by-character comparison of two equal-length strings, which your example show you aren't, this is a big topic that involves the concept of [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).  There is no single, perfect answer to this, so you may want to do some research.  There are libraries which can help with this.

Comment: This sounds like a variation of the Levenshtein difference algorithm. Here is a good post I've found on it: https://blog.paperspace.com/implementing-levenshtein-distance-word-autocomplete-autocorrect/#:~:text=The%20Levenshtein%20distance%20is%20a,transform%20one%20word%20into%20another.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [`difflib.ndiff()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff):

```py
from difflib import ndiff

str1 = "27785-74-1"
str2 = "27785%F274-1"
diff_between_str1_str2 = "".join(s[-1] for s in ndiff(str2, str1) if s[0] == "+")
```

Internally `ndiff()` uses [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) which based on [*Gestalt Pattern Matching*](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/ratcliffObershelp.html).